# Using USB-Serial adapter with WINE

Tags: usb, 18.04, wine, adapter

I want to use a USB-Serial adapter like this: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/FVT-USB-Linker-programmer-for-Car_60438143730.html?spm=a2700.8443308.0.0.49923e5f3vy0O0

With Wine, to configure/program a skateboard ESC.

I've downloaded Wine and gotten the program running like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEOl2.jpg

So the program is a little cut of, and then you can also see that the Serial adapter is not recognized!

I-ve tried using the command

```
ln -s /dev/tty0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com1
```

And

`ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com`

With no luck. 
How do I go about fixing this issue?
Best regards.

Comment: WINE is no good for that. A (Windows) VM may work with USB passtrought and drivers installed. I did it once to use Windows software to flash a tablet (the software also runs with Wine but wouldn't detect the tablet).

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted solution of

> ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com1

would have worked in earlier versions of Wine. This changed in Wine 2.8, now you need to manage the mapping using RegEdit.

> WINEPREFIX=~/.wine wine regedit

Add a string entry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wine\Ports` with a key of `COM1` and a value of `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

This problem is called out specifically in this blog post: https://www.scivision.dev/wine-serial-port-links/

And also mentioned in the official user guide: https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Serial_and_Parallel_Ports